# Hide/Show Table with Jquery - Option to hide/show individual table or show/hide all table

Tags: jquery, html

I have multiple tables that need I need to show/hide individually by clicking font awesome icon. The icon must change from right chevron (hide) to down chevron (open) and vice versa.

I also have a button to show/hide all the tables which is working fine, except I would like all the tables to be closed to start with.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".btn_hide").click(function(){
    $("table").hide();
  });
  $(".btn_show").click(function(){
    $("table").show();
  });
});
```

Here is a link to code https://jsfiddle.net/tdd75/hkyep1ma/59/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`toggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) and [`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) mechanism.

I added here some CSS and a class `show-table` and `tableLink` to make it much simpler

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".btn_hide").click(function(){
    $("table").hide();
    $("table").prev('p').removeClass('show-table');
  });
  $(".btn_show").click(function(){
    $("table").show();
    $("table").prev('p').addClass('show-table');
  });
  
  $(document).on('click','.tableLink',function(){
      $(this).parents('p').next().toggle();
      $(this).parents('p').toggleClass('show-table');
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  display:none;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

i.fa.fa-chevron-down {
  display:none
}

.show-table i.fa.fa-chevron-down {
  display:inline-block
}
.show-table i.fa.fa-chevron-right {
  display:none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<button class="btn_hide">Hide All</button>
<button class="btn_show">Show All</button>


<p>
  <a class="tableLink">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="tableLink"> Link to external page</a>
</p>

<table class="data_table">
  <tr>
    <th>tableheader</th>
    <th>tableheader</th>
    <th>tableheader</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>tabledata</td>
    <td>tabledata</td>
    <td>tabledata</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>tabledata</td>
    <td>tabledatag</td>
    <td>tabledata</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p>
  <a class="tableLink">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="tableLink"> Link to external page</a>
</p>

<table class="data_table hide-table">
  <tr>
    <th>tableheader</th>
    <th>tableheader</th>
    <th>tableheader</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>tabledata</td>
    <td>tabledata</td>
    <td>tabledata</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>tabledata</td>
    <td>tabledatag</td>
    <td>tabledata</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p>
  <a class="tableLink">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="tableLink"> Link to external page</a>
</p>

<table class="data_table hide-table">
  <tr>
    <th>tableheader</th>
    <th>tableheader</th>
    <th>tableheader</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>tabledata</td>
    <td>tabledata</td>
    <td>tabledata</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>tabledata</td>
    <td>tabledatag</td>
    <td>tabledata</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below works as you've requested. I've changed the classes for the hide/show all buttons so that they can be targetted individually.

Each individual show/hide button has been wrapped in a `div` with class `.table-wrapper`, which includes the corresponding `table` as a child. I think this is a little more robust than using the `.sibling()` command, and also lets you toggle more than one table by adding extra tables within that wrapper.

This way you can add/remove a `.hide-tables` class via the individual buttons or the all buttons. Some basic CSS then lets you perform the actions you were hoping.

Let me know if that wasn't what you were hoping.

---

## Demo

```js
// Add click event to individual hide buttons
$(".btn_hide").click(function() {

  // Travel up DOM tree to nearest .table-wrapper and add .hide-tables
  $(this).closest(".table-wrapper").toggleClass("hide-tables");

});

// Add click event to show all button
$(".btn_show_all").click(function() {

  // Remove hide-tables class from all wrappers
  $(".table-wrapper").removeClass("hide-tables");

});

// Add click event to hide all button
$(".btn_hide_all").click(function() {

  // Add hide-tables class to all wrappers
  $(".table-wrapper").addClass("hide-tables");

});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

.table-wrapper:not(.hide-tables) .fa-chevron-right {
  display: none;
}

.hide-tables .fa-chevron-right {
  display: inherit;
}

.hide-tables table,
.hide-tables .fa-chevron-down {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<button class="btn_hide_all">Hide All</button>
<button class="btn_show_all">Show All</button>

<div class="table-wrapper">
  <p>
    <a class="btn_hide">
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="#"> Link to external page</a>
  </p>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>tableheader</th>
      <th>tableheader</th>
      <th>tableheader</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>tabledata</td>
      <td>tabledata</td>
      <td>tabledata</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>tabledata</td>
      <td>tabledatag</td>
      <td>tabledata</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>

<div class="table-wrapper">
  <p>
    <a class="btn_hide">
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="#"> Link to external page</a>
  </p>

  <table class="data_table">
    <tr>
      <th>tableheader</th>
      <th>tableheader</th>
      <th>tableheader</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>tabledata</td>
      <td>tabledata</td>
      <td>tabledata</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>tabledata</td>
      <td>tabledatag</td>
      <td>tabledata</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
<div class="table-wrapper">

  <p>
    <a class="btn_hide">
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="#"> Link to external page</a>
  </p>

  <table class="data_table">
    <tr>
      <th>tableheader</th>
      <th>tableheader</th>
      <th>tableheader</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>tabledata</td>
      <td>tabledata</td>
      <td>tabledata</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>tabledata</td>
      <td>tabledatag</td>
      <td>tabledata</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```